im having trouble creating a dropdown navbar for my e-comm site using django
so my plan is to use a for loop to show all the possible categories instead of doing it manually used chatgpt but didn't help.
nav_bar.html(manually):
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Shop</a>
    
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category_summary' %}">All Categories</a></li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" href=""/></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' 'books' %}">Books</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

this is trying to use a for loop:
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Shop</a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category_summary' %}">All Categories</a></li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" href=""/></li>
        {% for category in categories %}
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' category|slugify %}">{{ category }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</li>

also created a view for the nav_bar.html page where I collect all the categories:
def sent_data(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'nav_bar.html', {'categories': categories})


can you provide your category model and the url?

kindly provide your URL and your model of the category. Do us a favor by showing us the error backtrace from your terminal so that we can figure it out for you.

Yes please add django URLS
